# Getting correct datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have a file to create log entries into a text file, but the datetime will not work, I have tried setting to `Utcnow` but to no luck

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ParticleFramework
{
    static class Log
    {
        private static FileStream file;
        public static string dateTime = String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", new DateTime());
        public static string logFile;

        public static Boolean Initialize(string f)
        {
            logFile = f;
            if (logFile != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    file = new FileStream(logFile, FileMode.Append);

                    plainWrite("");
                    plainWrite("");
                    Info("Particle Server logging started...");

                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static void Info(string text)
        {
            text = "[" + dateTime + "] " + text;
            plainWrite(text); 
        }

        public static void Error(string text)
        {
            text = "[ERROR]" + text;
            plainWrite(text);
        }

        private static void plainWrite(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file);

                sw.WriteLine(text);

                sw.Close();
                file = new FileStream(logFile, FileMode.Append);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

> [1/1/0001 00:00:00]

No matter how long the server runs, and how many lines are added to the log, the above datetime does not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `DateTime` that will be initialized to [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and then just keep reusing that.

Whenever you call `Info` you want to get the current `DateTime` with [`DateTime.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DateTime.UtcNow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static void Info(string text)
{
    text = string.Format("[{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}] {1}", DateTime.Now, text);
    plainWrite(text); 
}
```